# É correto usar bootstrap na finalização de um projeto?

Tags: bootstrap-4, organização-de-projeto

Olá, então ouvir muitos dizerem que usar **bootstrap** na finalização de um projeto e errado, eu particularmente não gosto muito de trabalhar com **front-end** então tento pular essa parte buscando algum tema responsivo pronto e adaptou ao meu gosto, porém como já ouvir muitos dizerem que é **errado** gostaria de saber se isso realmente é **verídico** ? e se sim, **porque** ?

Comment: O que exatamente você está "finalizando" se ainda não possui o front-end?

Comment: Não entendi qual a relação do Bootstrap com finalização de projeto, ainda mais dizer se é _errado_ (ou _correto_). O Bootstrap é apenas um framework.

Comment: Então eu pego um tema bootstrap adapto e completo com meu projeto e aí vem a finalização no caso com esse bootstrap entendeu ?

Comment: @Sam Então e porque muitos me disseram que e errado usar o bootstrap na versão final ou seja aquela que já está pronto o projeto e pode ser posto no ar, e que o correto é usar quando estiver criando o projeto para o ajudar no desenvolvimento mais pelo o que estou vendo e correto e não tem problema algum

Comment: Se vc colocar no ar sem carregar as bibliotecas do Bootstrap não vai funcionar.

Comment: @Sam No caso seria quando for finalizar o projeto tirar o tema bootstrap e criar seu próprio tema ou usar um sem ser bootstrap, me colocaram ele só como auxílio entendeu agora ?

Comment: Netflix, CNN e Salesforce, entre vários, vários outros sites, usam Bootstrap. Na universidade onde eu trabalho tanto o lado institucional quanto a intranet usam bootstrap. Estou curioso em relação aos argumentos de que seu uso é 'errado'.

Comment: Acho que vc se refere pq um tema provavelmente não vai usar todas as classes do Bootstrap, então seria "errado" importar o Bootstrap inteiro em produção já que vc só vai usar 30% dele. Mas não se preocupe, a situação é muito pior para quem usa WordPress pode acreditar.... Isso tudo que falam é baseado em opinião, eu preifiro deixar ele lá inteiro e se no futuro precisar de alguma classe já sei que está lá. Mas se vc quiser fazer um PostCSS ou um PurgCSS fica por sua conta. Se é que eu entendi a sua pergunta

Comment: @OnoSendai não disse que e errado eu queria saber se é , me disseram que era

Comment: @hugocsl Compreendido muito bem obrigado!

Comment: @ThiagoBomfim nesse caso o ônus de justificativa está com quem fez a afirmação.

Comment: Se vc puder trazer pra gente quais os motivos que levaram essa pessoa a falar isso, seria interessante

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap é um framework front-end. Usar ele desde o início ou em outra frase do projeto não tem problema algum. Desde que o framework esteja configurado correto com todas as classes importadas, tu podes usar no momento que quiser, como quiser. Isso não é errado pois não interfere no funcionamento do seu projeto. Ele é criado para se facilitar o desenvolvimento e ser colocado em produção.